# How to spawn at base station on EarthEasyStart multiplayer Space Engineers

Tags: hosting, space-engineers

I'm paying for a hosted Space Engineers server, and would like to use the Easy Start Earth Scenario with my friends.

The problem is that when we spawn in, it shows us a spawn menu when we join the server, instead of spawning us at the easy start base, as it does in single-player mode. None of the spawn options are in the base. If we choose to spawn in the lander and then fly to where the base is, the base's defenses shoot at us.

How do we fix this?

Here's our server config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MyConfigDedicated xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SessionSettings>
    <GameMode>Survival</GameMode>
    <InventorySizeMultiplier>1</InventorySizeMultiplier>
    <AssemblerSpeedMultiplier>1</AssemblerSpeedMultiplier>
    <AssemblerEfficiencyMultiplier>1</AssemblerEfficiencyMultiplier>
    <RefinerySpeedMultiplier>1</RefinerySpeedMultiplier>
    <OnlineMode>PUBLIC</OnlineMode>
    <MaxPlayers>8</MaxPlayers>
    <MaxFloatingObjects>256</MaxFloatingObjects>
    <EnvironmentHostility>NORMAL</EnvironmentHostility>
    <AutoHealing>true</AutoHealing>
    <EnableCopyPaste>false</EnableCopyPaste>
    <WeaponsEnabled>true</WeaponsEnabled>
    <ShowPlayerNamesOnHud>true</ShowPlayerNamesOnHud>
    <ThrusterDamage>false</ThrusterDamage>
    <CargoShipsEnabled>true</CargoShipsEnabled>
    <EnableSpectator>false</EnableSpectator>
    <RemoveTrash>false</RemoveTrash>
    <WorldSizeKm>0</WorldSizeKm>
    <RespawnShipDelete>true</RespawnShipDelete>
    <ResetOwnership>false</ResetOwnership>
    <WelderSpeedMultiplier>1</WelderSpeedMultiplier>
    <GrinderSpeedMultiplier>1</GrinderSpeedMultiplier>
    <RealisticSound>false</RealisticSound>
    <ClientCanSave>false</ClientCanSave>
    <HackSpeedMultiplier>0.33</HackSpeedMultiplier>
    <PermanentDeath>false</PermanentDeath>
    <AutoSaveInMinutes>5</AutoSaveInMinutes>
    <AutoSave>true</AutoSave>
    <SpawnShipTimeMultiplier>1</SpawnShipTimeMultiplier>
    <DestructibleBlocks>true</DestructibleBlocks>
    <EnableIngameScripts>true</EnableIngameScripts>
    <ViewDistance>20000</ViewDistance>
    <EnableToolShake>true</EnableToolShake>
    <VoxelGeneratorVersion>1</VoxelGeneratorVersion>
    <EnableOxygen>true</EnableOxygen>
  </SessionSettings>
  <Scenario>
    <TypeId>MyObjectBuilder_ScenarioDefinition</TypeId>
    <SubtypeId>EarthEasyStart</SubtypeId>
  </Scenario>
  <LoadWorld>Pandora</LoadWorld>
  <IP>173.199.86.147</IP>
  <SteamPort>27026</SteamPort>
  <ServerPort>27025</ServerPort>
  <AsteroidAmount>0</AsteroidAmount>
  <Administrators />
  <Banned />
  <Mods />
  <GroupID>0</GroupID>
  <ServerName>Defiant Guild Community Server</ServerName>
  <WorldName>Pandora</WorldName>
  <PauseGameWhenEmpty>false</PauseGameWhenEmpty>
  <IgnoreLastSession>false</IgnoreLastSession>
</MyConfigDedicated>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be in the same faction. Let the host create a faction, then let the other players join the faction. Now the turrets won't shoot at them since they don't see them as hostiles.

Same with sharing a medbay (respawn point), if you have a faction and the medbay sharing is on "share with faction" your friends can spawn there.